# Grails: Running datasource validation (dbCreate = 'validate') option

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm

Is there any way we can execute only the database schema validation in grails? Like we can `compile`, `clean` etc, can we do something like `grails dbvalidate` and get just the validation results.

I mean the validation that happens when specifying `dbCreate = 'validate'` in *DataSource.groovy* and executing `run-app`

The reason is that I want to be able to correct the tables myself and get the SQL for the `alter`/`create` commands (which are maintained separately in our environment here)

I understand that the Domain classes have to be loaded for this to be possible. So alternatively is there any way we can stop the execution of `run-app` after database schema validation - *in which case is there a way to avoid the steps that are irrelevant to db validation (like configuring spring security in my app's case)*

Comment: Have you tried `grails schema-export`?

Comment: No I haven't. In fact didn't know about it at all. :-) thanks for pointing out. Its name sounds like it should do the job.

Comment: I hope you already have [this](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/schema-export.html) for further reference.